# ERROR: Unable to download webpage: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden (caused by HTTPError()) in youtube-dl

Tags: http, youtube-dl, http-error, mpd, httpforbiddenhandler

I have paid for a course. And, some of those videos can be downloaded using the .mpd URL that can be found from the Network Tab.
But, some videos are showing the above mentioned error.

I ran the --verbose command and it gave me the following output-:

**This is what verbose gave-:**

```
[debug] System config: []
[debug] User config: []
[debug] Custom config: []
[debug] Command-line args: ['--verbose', 'https://bae.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/videos/2/dash/8a7aecbce5d83a906fd69980f49b94b1.mpd']
[debug] Encodings: locale cp1252, fs mbcs, out cp437, pref cp1252
[debug] youtube-dl version 2020.07.28
[debug] Python version 3.4.4 (CPython) - Windows-10-10.0.19041
[debug] exe versions: ffmpeg git-2020-06-26-7447045, ffprobe git-2020-06-26-7447045
[debug] Proxy map: {}
[generic] 8a7aecbce5d83a906fd69980f49b94b1: Requesting header
WARNING: Could not send HEAD request to https://bae.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/videos/2/dash/8a7aecbce5d83a906fd69980f49b94b1.mpd: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
[generic] 8a7aecbce5d83a906fd69980f49b94b1: Downloading webpage
ERROR: Unable to download webpage: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden (caused by HTTPError()); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; type  youtube-dl -U  to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
  File "C:\Users\dst\AppData\Roaming\Build archive\youtube-dl\ytdl-org\tmpq2whuxta\build\youtube_dl\extractor\common.py", line 627, in _request_webpage
  File "C:\Users\dst\AppData\Roaming\Build archive\youtube-dl\ytdl-org\tmpq2whuxta\build\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 2238, in urlopen
  File "C:\Python\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 470, in open
  File "C:\Python\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 580, in http_response
  File "C:\Python\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 508, in error
  File "C:\Python\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 442, in _call_chain
  File "C:\Python\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 588, in http_error_default
```

How can I fix this error and download those videos?